# Why I have not a number (NaN) output and not correct number

Tags: javascript, nan

How can I solve that NaN problem, I always get NaN on iva10 value when I enter numbers in form.

```js
function sum() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bene_significativo').value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('manodopera').value);
  var num3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('mark_up').value);

  document.getElementById('tot1').value = num1;
  document.getElementById('tot2').value = num2 + num3;
  document.getElementById('tot3').value = num1 + num2 + num3;

  var iva10 = document.getElementById('iva10').value = num1 - tot2;
}
```

```html
Bene significativo: <input type="text" id="bene_significativo" class="form-control" placeholder="Valore del bene significativo" aria-label="bene significativo" /><br />
Manodopera: <input type="text" id="manodopera" class="form-control" placeholder="Default input" aria-label="mandopera" /><br />
Mark-up: <input type="text" id="mark_up" class="form-control" placeholder="Default input" aria-label="mark_up" /><br />
<br />
<div><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sum()">Calcola</button></div>
<br />
Bene significativo: <input type="text" value="" id="tot1" /><br />
Manodopera: <input type="text" value="" id="tot2" /><br />
Totale complessivo prestazione: <input type="text" value="" id="tot3" /><br />
IVA 10%: <input type="text" value="" id="iva10" /><br />
IVA 22%: <input type="text" value="" id="iva22" />
```

I've also tried :

```
var iva10 = parseFloat(iva10);
```

but without success.

Thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: You never assigned `tot2`. What is `num1 - tot2` supposed to be?

Comment: I don't see that you declared tot2 as a variable, did you forget to do it or?

Comment: Since you never declared it as a variable, it's the same as `document.getElementById("tot2")`. This is the DOM element, not its numeric value. You can't subtract a DOM element from a number.

Comment: I think you want `num1 - (num2 + num3)`

Comment: it might also be a good practice to indicate input type='number', where applicable, to prevent user from inputting any non-number values in the field, as a precautionary measure.

Comment: @Barmar yes, you are right I didn't declare tot 2 ... sorry; how could I've declared it in the right way ? Thanks

Comment: @kesetovic yes, you are right too I didn't declare it

Comment: @Barmar you're right about DOM element ... in fact I changed the code in : var iva10 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('iva10').value = num1 - (num2 + num3)); and now it works !

Comment: @Vadym you're right too ... but how can I remove up/down arrows in input box when I set type="number" ? Thanks

Comment: @Mauro You can't. Use `type="text"` if you don't want it to add special controls specific to the type.

Comment: @Barmar at the moment I don't need to add special control specific to the type, so I think I'll leave type="text", but I've read that someone suggest to use use <input inputmode="numeric" ... /> what you think about ? Thanks

Comment: `inputmode` mainly just causes a customized virtual keyboard to be used on mobile devices, it doesn't have other effects as far as I know. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode So it could be a good compromise.